# TypeError: this.internal.getCurrentPageInfo is not a function in jspdf

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

When i try to convert html table to pdf using jspdf then get this error:

```
TypeError: this.internal.getCurrentPageInfo is not a function
```

Same code is used here https://codepen.io/someatoms/pen/adojWy

I took reference from https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js#L142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codepen example was using an old version of jspdf. Fixed the codepen example now by updating to the latest version.

Comment: there is one more question ...                                                                                         when a pdf generated ,in that there is a some space remaining in right side i.e. its used only 80% space of the page how i used whole page space

Comment: Checkout the margin option.

Comment: i define margin like this.........        let margins = {
   top: 40,
            bottom: 40,
            left: 40,
   right:40,
            width: 522
    };

Comment: pdf.fromHTML(
      divToPrint, 
      margins.left, 
      margins.top,
       { 
      'width': margins.width,
      'elementHandlers': {
          '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
         alert('here');
         return true;
           }
        };   
       },function(dispose) {       
      pdf.save('Test.pdf');
         }, margins);

Comment: fromHTML is not apart of autotable

Comment: can you share any link their is a proper documentation for autotable or any example

Comment: Check it out on github, search for jspdf autotable.